# get count with grep

Tags: text-processing, grep, solaris, numeric-data

im working on sun10 Solaris os,i have a process that returns table as by using this command `dmh -q 12` the below:

```
*PROFILE   PRIORITY   COMM_TYPE     QID    # OF MSGS   ATTRIBUTES/VALUES*
      13        999          DC      24            3     32  1865
      13        999          DC      94            1     32  1665
      13        999          DC     157            0     32  1961
      13        999          DC     188            2     32  1784
      13        999          DC     293            0     32  1625
      13        999          DC     294           31     32  1950
      13        999          DC     713            0     32  1601
      13        999          DC     838            0     32  1607
      13        999          DC    1458            0     32  1855
```

here im trying to get the total count of messages and store it in the variable 
I have tried this but it doesn't work with me:

```
dmh -q 12 | grep -v'# OF MSGS' | wc -l
```

the expected result should be 37

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
dmh -q 12 | awk 'NR > 1 { sum += $5 } END {print sum}'
```

This will sum all the values in column 5 and then print the total.

To store this in a variable use command substitution:

```
var=$(dmh -q 12 | awk 'NR > 1 { sum += $5 } END {print sum}')
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the input provided, you could use the `dc` utility:

```
$ dmh -q 12 | sed -e '1d;y/-/_/' | dc -e "[lMpq]sq [s0s0lM+sM]sm [?z0=qlmxcz0=?]s? 0sMl?x"
37
```

Note: This is assuming that you have a total of 7 columns in a row.